# Creating symbolic links to branches in SVN?

Tags: svn, branch

I'd like to create a symlink to a directory in SVN, eg. if I have

```
  branches/week-1/
  branches/week-2/
  ...
  branches/week-n/
```

and I'd like a directory,

```
  branches/current -> branches/week-n
```

that I can keep pointing to the latest *n* (by manually updating it). Is that possible?
If possible, I'd want to avoid checking out our entire repository, since it's huuuge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use svn externals property to create 'shortcuts'.  Although it sounds like you aren't using svn switching which you should be.

Doing an svn switch will be able to change between branches that you have with only the changed files.

Typically you have just one folder:

> C:\projects\myproject

And that folder has some branch checked out into it.

Then you do an svn switch into the other branch you'd like to go to.

It also sounds like you might have something backwards with how you are working with svn.   You can create weekly `tags` if you'd like like and do all of your development out of the trunk.

Comment: Actually, the scenario is more to the tune of, having a huge dump of a branches catalog, and wanting to cherry pick some current branches to another directory for easier checkout, while at the same time not disturbing the current branch structure...