# Mark current release in subversion

Tags: svn, release-management

I have multiple branches in SVN, with releases in it:

```
/branches/releaseApril
/branches/releaseMay
/branches/releaseJune
```

I want to mark the release currently in production as a branch:

```
/branches/production
```

If somebody commits something to /branches/production, I want the underlying branch to change. Like a symlink in SVN. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating symbolic links to branches in SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143853/creating-symbolic-links-to-branches-in-svn)

Comment: It seems to be impossible to create a link from one branch to another. Externals only work on subdirectories of something you checked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can remove a branch and make a new branch with the same name, but it is not possible to update the "pointer" of a branch to make it point somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish something similar to this with [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html).  But there are [drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338824/are-subversion-externals-an-antipattern).

Comment: I can't get this to work. It seems an svn:externals for /branches/production is only used when you check out /branches, not /branches/production.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an external to `^/branches/releaseJune` at `production` on `branches`, but that external will be seen when you checkout `branches`. There is no way to checkout `/branches/production` and start using it.

What you can do is have a `production` branch under branches ( basically a `production` folder under branches ) and define an external for it pointing to `/branches/releaseJune` etc. and using a folder like `current`. So when people checkout `/branches/production` they get a folder `current` which is `/branches/releaseJune`

Also, make sure you update the external when you do a new release to point it to the correct branch.

Answer (score 0):

Try `svn:external`. It might feel odd to use that but it should do what you want.

Another option is to make the branch `/branches/production` read only for everyone. That way, no one can accidentally change it but it means people have to switch to the right branch (and they might use the wrong one, so you're back at square one).